# Issue with Jupyter notebook and virtual environment pip

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, virtualenv, virtual-environment

I have created a virtual environment using the following commands:

```
python3 -m venv venv
.\venv\Scripts\activate.bat
pip3 install ipykernel
pip3 install jupyter
python3 -m ipykernel install --user --name=venv
```

I have created a Jupyter notebook using the venv that I created, but when I install a package in the virtual environment, it is not recognised in the notebook.

For example, I tried to install pandas using `pip3 install pandas`, but when I try and import it into my notebook I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'`

The module has installed in the right place `venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\`

Any ideas on what I should do?

**EDIT:**

I noticed that even though I created the notebook using the venv, it uses the normal python environment rather than the virtual one. Ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Well I think I solved it. If ran the following command:

```
python -c "import IPython"
```

Which just installs IPython in my venv.

Answer (score 0):

You need to restart the notebook kernel, it will probably work then.

In the future, in a notebook cell you can run

```
%%bash
pip install pandas
```

then you should be able to continue without restarting

Comment: Just tried it - nope, restarting the kernel doesn't do anything.